# How can I fix this error: Failed to perform checkout on agent: command failed. exit code: 128?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using TeamCity 2017.1.3 and I am receiving this error.

> Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass6471980056712706490.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop' command failed. exit code: 128

I already update my git, I reinstall teamcity and remove this lines from git configuration in \mingw64\etc\gitconfig file

> [credential]
>       helper = manager

But I am still having the error, I am using the same configuration that is working in another server, the only difference is the git and teamcity version, the VCS configuration is working ok because I already test the connections and is successful. I appreciate the help

Update: To make it work I went back to git 2.12 and disable credential manager option

Answer (score 0):

I just hit a similar issue:

```
[Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" clean -f -d -x' command failed.
exit code: 255
```

Teamcity version: 2017.2.3
Git version: 2.12.2.0

I have 6 agents. I changed 2 of them to Git 2.6.4 and it's working. Is there any issue with 2.12.2.0 ?